# Extract "permissions" from Manifest by Python

Tags: android, python, printing, permissions, manifest

I want to print the "permissions" from a Android Manifest file. I have already reverse engineered the apk and got the Android Manifest file and want to extract the permissions by using Python.

```
import string
test=string.printable
f=open('AndroidManifest.xml', 'r').read()
x=""
for n in f:
    if n in test:
     x+=n
    print (x)
```

This is my Python Script by which I can parse the XML file. How can I find the permissions and print it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html . The permissions needed by an app are given by the `<uses-permission>` tag(s).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Sir, I want to find all the permissions and print it using python. The code given here is already printing the whole AndroidManifest.xml file, but I want to print only the permissions used in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @Subhasis We can't do the work for you. I have provided some details about the ElementTree module in my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Sir, I am not asking to do the work. I am just asking the ways I can do it. I tried various ways after googling, it didn't work. That's why I came here.

Comment: @Subhasis Sir, please see my answer and see if it works.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Sir, it shows a error.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Comment: @Subhasis I have edited the code. Also see the links I have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML parsing is a very common task and by writing a module to do that you are reinventing the wheel only to end up with a rough non-circular design.

Python provides a much better designed, rounded wheel for that: [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). You can use this module to effortlessly parse XML files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("AndroidManifest.xml").getroot()
permissions = root.findall("uses-permission")

for perm in permissions:
    for att in perm.attrib:
        print("{}\t:\t{}\n".format(att, perm.attrib[att]))
```

This will print all the attributes of the `<uses-permission>` tag. Refer to the link above for more details.

**Note: For more details on the structure of the Manifest file, see the [App Manifest page on Android Devs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).**

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for guiding me through this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If it worked, you can accept this answer by clicking the tick.

Comment: I did that Sir. Thanks for the suggestion